# Dependency problems for libreoffice-common on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice

Whenever I try to upgrade my system (`apt update && apt upgrade -y`)

I get this:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories.
If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal:
 apt-get install -f

Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libreoffice-core: Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.3.2) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but 2:4.21-2build1 is installed
                  Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.16) but 2:3.45-1ubuntu2 is installed
libreoffice-pdfimport: Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
libreoffice-style-breeze: Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
libreoffice-style-colibre: Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
libreoffice-style-elementary: Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
libreoffice-style-tango: Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
```

How do I solve this? its very frustrating. I have tried to autoclean, autoremove and all kind of stuff without knowing what I'm really doing.

`ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` shows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Jan 17  2019 brave-browser.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  111 Nov  1 15:42 brave-browser-release-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  111 Oct 29 21:07 brave-browser-release-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  111 Nov  1 15:42 brave-browser-release-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 Nov  1 15:42 cordova-ubuntu-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 Oct 29 21:07 cordova-ubuntu-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 Nov  1 15:42 cordova-ubuntu-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  304 Nov  1 15:42 cwchien-ubuntu-gradle-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  304 Oct 29 21:07 cwchien-ubuntu-gradle-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  304 Nov  1 15:42 cwchien-ubuntu-gradle-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166 Nov  1 15:42 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166 Oct 29 21:07 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166 Nov  1 15:42 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Nov  1 15:42 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  221 Oct 29 21:07 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190 Nov  1 15:42 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225 Nov  1 15:42 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225 Oct 29 21:07 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225 Nov  1 15:42 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  208 Nov  1 15:42 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  208 Oct 29 21:07 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  208 Nov  1 15:42 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Nov  1 15:42 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  163 Oct 29 21:07 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  163 Nov  1 15:42 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68 Nov  1 15:42 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  164 Nov  1 15:42 linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  164 Oct 29 21:07 linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  164 Nov  1 15:42 linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  200 Nov  1 15:42 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  200 Oct 29 21:07 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  200 Nov  1 15:42 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Nov  1 15:42 nodesource.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Oct 29 21:07 nodesource.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Nov  1 15:42 nodesource.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  169 Nov  1 15:42 oguzhaninan-ubuntu-stacer-disco.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  169 Oct 29 21:07 oguzhaninan-ubuntu-stacer-disco.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  169 Nov  1 15:42 oguzhaninan-ubuntu-stacer-disco.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  219 Nov  1 15:42 opera-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  219 Oct 29 21:07 opera-stable.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  219 Nov  1 15:42 opera-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Nov  1 15:42 playonlinux.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Oct 29 21:07 playonlinux.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78 Nov  1 15:42 playonlinux.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   90 Nov  1 15:42 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   90 Oct 29 21:07 skype-stable.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   90 Nov  1 15:42 skype-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Nov  1 15:42 slack.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225 Oct 29 21:07 slack.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Nov  1 15:42 slack.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1575 Nov  1 15:42 teamviewer.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1575 Oct 29 21:07 teamviewer.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1509 Dec  8  2018 teamviewer.list.dpkg-dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1575 Nov  1 15:42 teamviewer.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Nov  1 15:42 ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Oct 29 21:07 ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Nov  1 15:42 ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 ubuntu-sdk-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Oct 29 21:07 ubuntu-sdk-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 ubuntu-sdk-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-disco.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Oct 29 21:07 videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-disco.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-disco.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 videolan-ubuntu-stable-daily-disco.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Oct 29 21:07 videolan-ubuntu-stable-daily-disco.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 Nov  1 15:42 videolan-ubuntu-stable-daily-disco.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  227 Nov  1 15:42 vscode.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  227 Oct 29 21:07 vscode.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  227 Nov  1 15:42 vscode.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  312 Nov  1 15:42 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  312 Oct 29 21:07 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  312 Nov  1 15:42 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Nov  1 15:42 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Oct 29 21:07 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Nov  1 15:42 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Nov  1 15:42 xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Oct 29 21:07 xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Nov  1 15:42 xorg-edgers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
```

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/34.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 300444 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a6.3.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.3.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/personas/dark/preview.png.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.3.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-cache policy libreoffice-common

```
libreoffice-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install -f` ?

Comment: Also, add the output of `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to your question above. After pasting the output, please highlight it and click the "code" markup button "{}" to format your output, so it is easier for us to read.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-common` to the question.

Comment: Related: [Unable to update or install anything after moving to another country](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169657/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-after-moving-to-another-country)

Comment: Your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` contains mixed PPAs for `libreoffice` from different releases. I suggest you fix these first.

Comment: @Raffa kan du be more specific? which one to remove

Comment: can you please post the output of `sudo -l` and  `ls -l -d /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/personas/dark/`

Answer (score 0):

This morning, I just ran `apt get update && apt get upgrade` and it installed successfully. Very weird.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
apt update
```

and then

```
apt upgrade --fix-broken --fix-missing
```

It might solve some of your issues. If not, please provide more info, like sources, logs from /var/log/apt/* and how did you reach this point...

P.S. always run `apt moo` in the end... XD