# unable to install apt or run get update

Tags: resolv.conf

For no apparent reason my Ubuntu suddenly stopped letting me install apts
for example sudo apt-get update gets this response:

> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>     Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
>   Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
>     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

Some answers suggested adding namespace 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 to resolv.conf as a first step however I cannot edit that file as it is a linked file type. I cannot modify it no matter what I do...

Using Ubuntu 68ubuntu1~18.04.1 on VMware partition of PC.  This is a private install. Not an organization
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: To start with, 1) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and 2) which release number?  3) Reboot the OS. Does the problem persist after a reboot?  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Welcome! In addition to @K7AAY comment, can you specify if this is a private or an organization network? Are you able to manually browse from a browser to that  url? "Could not resolve x" error usually means your client was unable to reach a dns, or the dns has no record of such url, usually due to network related errors / changes.

Comment: does ```ping google.com``` work? what about ```ping 8.8.8.8```

Comment: ping google does not work … but have punted on this … did a complete reinstall of Ubuntu and problem went away for now.  But the downside is I may never know what I did to cause this or fix it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1169657/968501

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your DNS,
the DNS is configured in your resolv.conf, if this file 'dont exit' but is pointing to another file is not a problem, mine is too
check with
ls -ltr /etc/resolv.conf
mine is pointing like that /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
add in this file this line
nameserver 1.1.1.1

So basically... only need to run:
sudo echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf