# Have Problem update and install most of new apps - 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: updates, downloads

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

It's been awhile that I have problem on updating and downloading new apps.
I can't open the Software centre and when I try to download app through terminal, it keeps showing this message:
`E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-63-generic needs to be reinstalled`, but I can't find an archive for it.

I am really not good with technology. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1228877/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Complete output, please - don't summarize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update or install anything after moving to another country](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169657/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-after-moving-to-another-country)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)` - have you tried this? Show output of: `ls /boot/ | grep vmlinuz`

Answer (score 1):

The latest Linux kernel headers in Ubuntu 18.04 is version linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt autoremove # removes linux-headers-4.15.0-63-generic
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```