# Updating from such repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository, wacom

I'm trying to install Wacom Tablet Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04, Code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details`
```

I have tried `--allow-unauthenticated` But it doesn't work. I also have deleted the Docker repository, as Raffa said in comments. Still no dice. Does anyone know any fixes? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force update from unsigned repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository)

Comment: Sadly no, It doesn't :(

Comment: The error is about Docker repository not about the one you added. Try disabling the Docker repository or removing it and see how it works. Or follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169696/968501) to reset your repositories and clear third party ones and start allover again.

Comment: Maybe, It says it is only on Ubuntu 14, While im using 18.

Comment: @Neichello try adding the `--allow-insecure-repositories` option to your `add-apt-repository`, please.

Comment: @fboaventura Hi, --allow-insecure-repositories just shows up as command not found.