# Apt-get does not install packages, apt-get update does not work

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

A few days ago, apt-get stopped installing packages successfully.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on Raspberry Pi 2.

I want to install Idle 3 so I can do a python program. But when I run `sudo apt-get install idle3`, I get these errors:

```
    Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates/universe armhf idle-python3.6 all 3.6.9-1~18.04
    404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/p/python3.6/idle-python3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
    404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I did run `apt-get update` before running this command. It also was not successful, even though i did not realize it. It gave these errors:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
Err:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates/main i386 Packages               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
Err:35 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-security/main i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
Err:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-backports/main i386 Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::22 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dtcooper.github.io/raspotify raspotify InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Please help! I need to be able to install packages!

#### Edit - System Info

```
REPOSITORIES INFO
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic main

RELEASE INFO
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

KERNEL INFO
Linux raspberrypi 4.15.0-1060-raspi2 #64-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 25 18:03:34 UTC 2020 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Include in your question the output of `echo "REPOSITORIES INFO" && grep -R "deb http*" /etc/apt/* | grep -v "list.save" && echo -e "\nRELEASE INFO" && cat /etc/*release* && echo -e "\nKERNEL INFO" && uname -a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update or install anything after moving to another country](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169657/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-after-moving-to-another-country)

Comment: Gyru, I showed the output of the command you showed in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, Raffa, I tried everything in that question and it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First error

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

This doesn't have a i386 component. Plus, I don't know why you want i386 packages on a Raspberry Pi.

Therefore

```
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Try prepending the line with `[arch=armhf,arm64]`, ie:

```
deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

And check the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

### Second error

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

That repository doesn't have a `bionic` component.