# apt removes itself

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, dependencies

```
max@max-Vostro-5568:~/Desktop$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 snapd : Breaks: apt (< 1.6.3) but 1.6.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Further I try to eliminate these problems, but self-removal occurs.

```
max@max-Vostro-5568:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 linux-headers-5.3.0-28
  linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic
  linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic
  python3-debconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,896 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] Yes, do as I say!
(Reading database ... 223329 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apt (1.6.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
max@max-Vostro-5568:~/Desktop$ apt
bash: /usr/bin/apt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try option #2 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) and see if it helps.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: Edit you question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`. Looks like possible mixed-version sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04. Try this in a terminal:

**For AMD64 machines:**

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

---

**Or for Intel x86 machines:**

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

---

**Notice:**

- For other releases of Ubuntu, please search [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt) and select your release then download the suitable version of APT and install it like above.
- Refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169696/968501) and fix your sources list and PPA's.
- Always run `sudo apt update` before installing or upgrading any packages.
- If you have `aptitude` installed, you can use it to install APT instead ( *after checking your repositories list is correct by referring to the linked answer above* ) like so:

  `sudo aptitude update`

  then:

  `sudo aptitude install apt`

Comment: dpkg: regarding apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb containing apt:
 apt breaks aptitude (<< 0.8.10)
  aptitude (version 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) is present and installed.

Comment: @MaxB Fix your repositories sources list like in the linked answer then do `sudo aptitude update` then `sudo aptitude install apt`. You appear to have `aptitude` installed.