# when doing upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 there is an error

Tags: apt, lubuntu, gcc

I got this error when doing upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 and power-lost in the middle.

This is what the error looked like, and apt-get install -f does not fix it.

---

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.12) but 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3 is installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is installed
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 1.6.12) but 2.0.2 is installed
 libapt-pkg6.0 : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installed
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: gcc-8-base:i386 (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libmpx2 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10-20200425-1ubuntu2 is installed
              Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-10-base:i386 (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Also $grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/samoilov-lex-ubuntu-aftl-stable-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/samoilov-lex-ubuntu-aftl-stable-bionic.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful main
```

$ apt-cache policy apt apt-utils libgcc1 libatomic1

```
apt:
  Installed: 2.0.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.12 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.6ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
apt-utils:
  Installed: 1.6.12
  Candidate: 1.6.12
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.12 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.6ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgcc1:
  Installed: 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Candidate: 1:10-20200416-0ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
     1:10-20200416-0ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libatomic1:
  Installed: 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Candidate: 10-20200416-0ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
     10-20200416-0ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8-20180414-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: From 18.04 to 20.04 LTS I guess. Try to install Aptitude with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Also add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1233600/edit).

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy apt apt-utils libgcc1 libatomic1` to the question body.

Comment: You have a big mess of packages and their versions. We need to revert them to 18.04 LTS versions. Try `sudo apt-get install apt=1.6.12`.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: We can try to revert GCC toolchain with `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` , `sudo ppa-purge:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and then continue.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Try fixing your repositories list and PPAs following [this answew](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169696/968501) then follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) to fix missing and broken packages and upgrade.