# apt gives "Clearsigned file" error

Tags: apt, 19.10

I get the following error when i use `apt-get`

```
Reading package lists... Error!                              
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It prevents Synaptic Package Manager from opening and is also shown on the notification area. How can i get rid of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1169696/968501 check your repositories and try to clear 3rd party PPAs

Comment: Hi @Raffa thank you for quick response. I did remove sources.list.d. It does update now. What i understand is, this will not affect the installed packages but they no longer will get auto update right?

Comment: Yes, they will continue to function but no updates will be proposed for 3rd party installed packages when you run `sudo apt-get update`