# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS shows that update cannot be done securely due to lack of Release File

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, when I type in `sudo apt update` in the terminal, I get:

```
Hit:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease              
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vikoadi/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vikoadi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vikoadi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1169657/968501

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you are using KDE or KDEconnect indicator application.  The error is from said source, vikoadi.  Remove the said source from the list for the timebeing and try the update again and you should use `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.  Make sure you have selected and opted for LTS versions in the software and update's update tab.