# I am unable to update my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, update-manager, repository

I am kindly requesting for some help.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 and recently I don't know exactly what I did to my computer and I can no longer update it.

When I try to update it using the the command `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jkist/xUbuntu_18.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG FE76CD923B7B38C4 home:jkist OBS Project <home:jkist@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jkist/xUbuntu_18.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am have been experiencing this problem now four days. I have tried to get some information from internet but still i have failed to update my laptop.

Anyone know how I can get out of this mess please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update or install anything after moving to another country](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169657/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-after-moving-to-another-country)

Answer (score 1):

Packages in a repository can be cryptographically signed. That's to ensure that the packages have not been tampered with. If they *had* been tampered with, the signature wouldn't be correct anymore.

To check the signature, your system needs the *public key* of the repository in question. Those keys have kind of a "shelf life", meaning they expire after a certain date. That's what happened in your case, as you can see from the error message:

> The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG FE76CD923B7B38C4

`EXPKEYSIG` hints to "the signature key has expired" ;) And `FE76CD923B7B38C4`  is the id of the key in question.

So you need to get the renewed, current public key. The exact method how to get that depends on how the repository in question offers its keys. Some offer specific packages that install the public key. Others put the key in the repository as special file that you download and install with the `apt-key` command. Others still put the key on special key servers, where you can access them with the `apt-key` command. You'll want to refer to the description of the repository in question, it is probably explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-add the GPG key for this repository by the following commands and update package cache:

```
wget -nv -O - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:jkist/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

If the above commands fail - then disable this repository using Software & Updates application.